# Tags for improving a closed question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, edits

I notice we must have a tag on a question on meta sites that's either [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [support](/questions/tagged/support), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

1. so I guess requiring help to improve a question is like discussion?
2. also besides which of those four is right, what tags usually are used for improving closed questions? Do I just look up tags that continue 'clos' (closing, closed, etc.) or 'edit' (editing, edited), etc.?
3. I think we should have a standard tag that's like 'improved-closed' for such questions or idk. What do you think?

E.g.,

*[Please help me improve my question on 'dishonest mistake' (re the term 'honest mistake')](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15179/please-help-me-improve-my-question-on-dishonest-mistake-re-the-term-honest-m)*

Comment: In the non-meta question, all the meta talk (including "Edit 1" and "Edit 2") ought to be moved out of the question and into comments (or deleted). That is what comments are for (despite the name).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On meta sites, you do need to choose at least one "required tag." For this instance, you should probably just choose [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). The [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag *sounds* promising, but it's geared more towards support for site features and how to use them.

Getting into the optional tags is tricky, because not every meta site has the same tags. If I wanted to ask about a closed question of mine on Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow's meta, I'd probably use the [discussion], [reopen-closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-closed), and [specific-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) tags. However, not all meta sites *have* a [reopen-closed] tag like Meta Stack Overflow does. On SciFi's meta, I'd probably use [specific-question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) and [closed-questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-questions). It really does depend on the site.

I personally wouldn't worry about the tags *too* much though. Getting it right the first time is nice, but tags can always be edited by a passing veteran with full edit privileges.

> I think we should have a standard tag that's like 'improved-closed' for such questions or idk. What do you think?

Eh. Maybe. If the site you frequent doesn't have a clear tag for such a purpose, maybe you should bring *that* up on that site's meta and determine how you should handle it. This feels like something that should be managed on a per-site basis.

Comment: ok thanks Spevacus. looks like i'll have to do this on like 5+ sites. hmmm....